# Insert documents into task form - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any option to insert attachments into task's form?

I mean, when I receive a task to approve/disapprove, I need to insert a document (txt or .doc).

Answer (score 0):

**In designer you can add a custom script for attachment under some div , should work** -
*

```
<tr>
    <td  class="ms-formlabel">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr><font color="#585858" size="2">Attachment</font><span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
    </nobr>
    </h3>
    </td>
    <td  class="ms-formbody" id="attachmentsOnClient" style="width: 434px">

    <span dir="ltr">
    <input type="file" name="fileupload0" id="getFile" size="56" class="two" /></span>

    </td>
    <td width="100px"  class="ms-formbody">

    <span id="idSpace"></span>
    </td>   
    </tr>
```